# MVC 3 validate 2 fields in different classes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, viewmodel

I have a viewmodel with 2 objects inside

```
class trip
{
    public DateTime returnedDate {get;set;}
    ....
}

class personData
{
   public DateTime PassportExpDate {get;set;}
    ....
}
```

The ViewModel contains these 2 objects

How do I implement validation so that PassportExpDate > returnedDate

Comment: I would implement a [`Remote` validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A scenario rendered completely trivial with [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) and PITA with Data Annotations.

So here are the simple steps:

1. Install the `FluentValidation.MVC3` NuGet package
2. Register the FV provider in `Application_Start`:

   ```
   FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
   ```
3. Design your view model (remark: this is not a pure view model, pure view models should not be making any references to domain models, but I will leave it that way for the purpose of this demonstration):

   ```
   [Validator(typeof(MyViewModelValidator))]
   public class MyViewModel
   {
       public Trip Trip { get; set; }
       public PersonData PersonData { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Now define the corresponding FV validator for the view model:

   ```
   public class MyViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyViewModel>
   {
       public MyViewModelValidator()
       {
           RuleFor(x => x.Trip.ReturnDate)
               .LessThan(x => x.PersonData.PassportExpDate)
               .WithMessage("You wanna get arrested?");
       }
   }
   ```
5. Controller:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           var model = new MyViewModel
           {
               Trip = new Trip
               {
                   ReturnDate = new DateTime(2012, 8, 13)
               },
               PersonData = new PersonData
               {
                   PassportExpDate = new DateTime(2012, 8, 12)
               }
           };
           return View(model);
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
       {
           return View(model);
       }
   }
   ```
6. View:

   ```
   @model MyViewModel

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       <div>
           @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Trip.ReturnDate)
           @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Trip.ReturnDate)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Trip.ReturnDate)
       </div>
       <div>
           @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PersonData.PassportExpDate)
           @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PersonData.PassportExpDate)
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.PersonData.PassportExpDate)
       </div>

       <button type="submit">OK</button>
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This seems to work. I do have one more issue with my viewmodel. I am expecting an array of PersonData. How does the definition of the validator changes? thanks